# What pattern can be used to create an object of one class, but fill its properties in different ways?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a class like this

```
public class OwnerWithholding
    {

        private decimal ManagementFeePct;

        private decimal TotalManagementFee;

        private decimal OperationalFeesPct;

        private decimal TotalOperationalFees;

}
```

And  I have calculation method that create object of this class, fill it with some arithmetic operations, and return this object.

```
public OwnerWithholding CalculationMethod1(Reservation r, SqlConnection conn)
        {
            OwnerWithholding result = new OwnerWithholding();

           // result.ManagementFeePct  = some data from Fees table in DB + value 
           //from another db - constant value..

           // Also with other properties - with some operations on data

           //result.TotalManagementFee = ..
           // result.OperationalFeesPct = ..
           // result. TotalOperationalFees = ..

            return result;
        }
```

And now it works fine.
But this calculation method is just one option for populating data.

There is another calculation method, implemented in a completely different way, but filling exactly the same properties of the object. And I may have more of them.

I need a pattern that would allow me to create objects of the same class, just indicating the calculation method that is needed.
I like the strategy pattern , where the algorithms will be the methods that fill the objects that called them.
But it doesn’t look very good. 
Maybe a factory method would be more appropriate here, but I don’t know how to implement it.

Comment: Are you looking for the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)?

Comment: If you want a Factory pattern, perhaps abstract out the common properties into an AbstractFactory and then have concrete Factories implement specific "types" of this object. So anytime you have a new "type" come along, you'll need a concrete Factory implementer.
But the Factory, makes more sense when object creation happens from multiple places in your code.

Comment: @Rakesh , Yes, I have creation of this object in several places in my code, and each place need object with specific data in it, according on chosen option

Comment: Also, are you saying that just one of property values is set in a dynamic manner, of so, the Builder is a good pattern as well, like @Corak just suggested.

Comment: @Corak , don't think so - builder is for several creating steps that can be different, but I have only one

Comment: @Rakesh, sorry, maybe I wrote wrong -  all object properties are set in this method.

Comment: @AtlasPromotion - but that one step is different for different purposes, right? No one is stopping you from having a builder with just one step. - i.e. you could have a `BuilderWithCalculationMethodA` and `BuilderWithCalculationMethodB` etc. -- if you can factor out the calculation methods, you come close to the strategy pattern. Why does that not "look very good"?

Comment: Thanks for builder idea, I will think about it. It does not look very good, because in this case I have to do something like this: ```calculationMethod.SetCalculationStrategy(new CalculationMethod1());
            return calculationMethod.CreateAndFillObject; ```  Don't I?

Comment: @AtlasPromotion - Are these different "types " predefined, i.e. you can only have 5 of these types,a s opposed to any possible number.
If the combinations are infinite, a constructor is the way to do it, no point in having a Factory - just letting you know.

Comment: @Rakesh , types - calculation methods?

Comment: @AtlasPromotion - Yes, calculation methods

Comment: @Rakesh, sorry, don't understand about infinite combinations - now I have only 2 methods, but in future I may have more of them

Comment: @Corak, sorry, forgot to mention you in comment:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Going by the OPs comments now, it looks like just ONE method in the class needs to be set in multiple ways.
The Template pattern (or the Builder) are better fits in this case, not the Factory.

Template Pattern.

a. Abstract Base class that set default properties, but leaves out one property (Get Ingredients) to be populated by the concrete classes.

```
    public abstract class PizzaCreator
    {
        public abstract string GetIngredients { get; }
        public string Bake { get; set; } = "Bake at 400F for 30 minutes";
        public string Deliver { get; set; } = "Deliver in custom box";
    }
```

b. Two Pizza classes, for now just overriding the abstract property

```
    public class CheesePizza : PizzaCreator
    {
        public override string GetIngredients
        {
            get { return GetMyIngredients(); }
        }

        string GetMyIngredients()
        {
            return "Lots of Cheese!";
        }
    }

    public class PepperoniPizza : PizzaCreator
    {
        public override string GetIngredients
        {
            get { return GetMyIngredients(); }
        }

        string GetMyIngredients()
        {
            return "Lots of Meats!";
        }
    }
```

Here I'm creating instances of the Pizza

```
            var pepPizza = new PepperoniPizza();
            var chessePizza = new CheesePizza();
```

*You could even have these creations routed through a Factory class/method.*

**Original answer**:
Here is the Abstract Factory Pattern.

This code goes into the Factory class library.

a.ICar interface

```
    public interface ICar
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        int Doors { get; set; }
        string EngineCapacity { get; set; }
    }
```

b.Abstract Car Factory

```
    public abstract class AbstractCarFactory
    {
        public abstract ICar CreateCar(CarType type);
    }
```

c.Two Concrete Cars -

```
    internal class NissanPickUpTruck : ICar
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public int Doors { get; set ; }
        public string EngineCapacity { get ; set ; }
    }

    internal class NissanSportsCar: ICar
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public int Doors { get; set; }
        public string EngineCapacity { get; set; }
    }
```

d.Concrete Factory

```
    public class NissanFactory : AbstractCarFactory
    {
        public override ICar CreateCar(CarType type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case CarType.PickupTruck:
                    return new NissanPickUpTruck{Name = "Titan", Doors = 6, EngineCapacity = "V12"};
                case CarType.SportsCar:
                    return new NissanSportsCar{Name = "350Z", Doors = 2, EngineCapacity = "V6"};
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally the calls from an external project

```
            var nissanFactory = new NissanFactory();
            var sportsCar = nissanFactory.CreateCar(CarType.SportsCar);
            var pickUpTruck = nissanFactory.CreateCar(CarType.PickupTruck);
```

**But like the other comment, the Builder is something worth checking out as well.**

Comment: And if I have calculation methods, should I place this different methods in different classes - such as NissanPickup and NissanSport? And return object in this method, and then just call ```case CarType.PickupTruck:
                    return NissanPickupCalcMethod();``` Or it will better if I have constructors in this classes instead of method?

Comment: Yes, different concrete classes with the appropriate calculations

Comment: Hold on, you are returning concrete classes, not just calculation methods, the word methods is confusing, I don't know if you mean "methods" in the C# sense or "methods" in the business rule sense.

Comment: In the C# sense. If I return concrete classes, I cannot pass all values for their properties in new NissanPickUpTruck{Name = "Titan", Doors = 6, EngineCapacity = "V12"}; because I have huge methods in which this values are calculated and are assigned to properties of object

Comment: If you want to update just ONE property in a class in multiple ways, both the Builder and the Template patterns are what you need. In the Factory, you are instantiating concrete classes, not just assigning one property.

Comment: Hm, Template pattern? In which we have skeleton of algorithm and then add specific steps in subclasses? But how can I use it in my case?

Comment: Check this link - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/template_pattern.htm
It explains how to use the Template pattern.

Comment: Updated to include Template pattern.

Comment: @Rakesh Good answer but it would have added a lot more value had you stuck to the example given by the OP that does not contain Pizzas or Cars IMO.

Comment: :) I did not understand his business rules, I already got it wrong once. I felt that Cars and Pizzas are easy to understand and follow - but I agree that his objects in the examples would have been better.

Comment: @AtlasPromotion - Were you able to use the Template pattern to solve your problem?